# Как узнать какая версия websphere установлена?

Tags: websphere

Есть сервер вебсферы и доступ в веб-консоль управления. Как узнать, какая это версия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте команду versionInfo. Эта команда генерирует отчет из данных XML-файлов в папке свойств и версии.

Для Unix и Linux: WAS_PATH/bin/versionInfo.sh
Для Windows: WAS_PATH\bin\versionInfo.bat

Comment: Как дополнение, на главном окне если промотать направо до конца - отображено окно с версией.